# Foursquare - get user registration date

Tags: geolocation, location, foursquare

Is there any way to get user registration date and time (like created_at for checkins)?

Maybe there are undocumented feature in https://api.foursquare.com/v2/users/self? Like adding parameter &field=created_at

Tried to get that date from "created_at" parameter of first checkin(or from created_at of "newbie" badge), but many users are checkining first time after months they have registered. So, how to know who is "older"?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, we do not currently offer join date information from our API. As you've noted, a reasonable proxy for that information is the date of their first check-in.